# Pure Javascript - convert an array into a csv format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having an issue when I try to convert my array to a CSV format.

Array is as follows

```
test.names = [

    {
        testSuiteId: 111111,
        testSuiteName: "Name",
        tests: [{
                testId: 222222,
                testName: "test 1"
            }, {
                testId: 333333,
                testName: "test 2"
            }, {
                testId: 444444,
                testName: "test 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        testSuiteId: 222222,
        testSuiteName: "Name2",
        tests: [{
                testId: 222222,
                testName: "test 1"
            }, {
                testId: 333333,
                testName: "test 2"
            }, {
                testId: 444444,
                testName: "test 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I use the following to convert this to an JSON string.

```
let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(test.names);
let csvReadyData = ConvertToCSV(jsonObject);
```

However I end up with the following

```
111111,Name,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
222222,Name2,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I'm wanting to get

```
111111,Name,222222, test 1,
111111,Name,333333, test 2,
111111,Name,444444, test 3,
222222,Name2,222222, test 1,
222222,Name2,333333, test 2,
222222,Name2,444444, test 3,
```

Or even this

```
111111,Name,222222, test 1,333333, test 2,444444, test 3
222222,Name2,test 1,333333, test 2,444444, test 3
```

Comment: One approach would be to explode the original array so there is not a nested array, before going to the csv converter

Comment: Please provide the value of `test.names` in JavaScript notation, not as a copy paste from some console output.

Comment: Where do you define `ConvertToCSV` or get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var flatArray = [];

test.names.forEach(name => {
    name.tests.forEach(test => {
        flatArray.push({
            testSuiteId: name.testSuiteId,
            testSuiteName: name.testSuiteName,
            testId: test.testId,
            testName: test.testName
        });
    });
});

console.log(flatArray);
```

That logic should explode the nested arrays into a single array, with the parent information repeating, as you have shown you desire in the resulting output.  You should be able to give that array to your `ConvertToCSV` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, something like this:

```js
let test = {};
test.names = [
{
testSuiteId: 111111,
testSuiteName: "Name",
tests: [
{testId: 222222, testName: "test 1"},
{testId: 333333, testName: "test 2"},
{testId: 444444, testName: "test 3"}
]},
{
testSuiteId: 222222,
testSuiteName: "Name2",
tests:[
{testId: 222222, testName: "test 1"},
{testId: 333333, testName: "test 2"},
{testId: 444444, testName: "test 3"}
]}
];
let csv_result = "";
test.names.forEach(el => {
  csv_result += el.testSuiteId + ",";
  csv_result += el.testSuiteName + ",";
  el.tests.forEach(testel => {
     csv_result += testel.testId + ",";
     csv_result += testel.testName + ",";
  })
});
console.log(csv_result);
```

Comment: He said "Array is as follows".

Comment: ...and before that *'..Object array'* in the header and first sentence, so, agree, it is somewhat confusing